# How do I represent dependency injection in sequence diagram?

Tags: dependency-injection, uml, sequence-diagram

We are building an ASP.Net Web API project using Repository pattern with Dependency Injection. I don't want to create an incomplete diagram, but I also don't want to have much details on it.

What would be the right or at least the suggested way to ilustrate DI in sequence diagrams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't present the wiring of your components in a sequence diagram. The wiring of your components is an infrastructural concern, but a sequence diagram is meant to show how components interact with each other. Trying to add the wiring of your components in your sequence diagrams just obfuscates the diagrams without adding any useful information.

When you take a peek in [Dependency Injection, Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://manning.com/seemann2), you'll see that we (i.e. [Mark Seemann](https://blog.ploeh.dk/about/) and I) sometimes *do* actually show the DI composition process, but that's mainly because the book tries to teach DI. Take a look at figure 4.5 ([page 95](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-4/section-4-2)), for instance:

[image: Figure 4.5 of DIPPP]

Besides the interaction between the two components (HomeController and ProductService), the diagram shows how the two components are composed by the [Composition Root](https://mng.bz/K1qZ), before they are used. This is especially useful in this case, as the section teaches how [Constructor Injection](https://mng.bz/oN9j) works.

For understanding the *interaction between components*, however, this level of detail is unneeded. Most sequence diagrams in the book, therefore, hide these details, such as figure 6.6 ([page 181](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/section-6-2-1)):

[image: Figure 6.6 of DIPPP]

Comment: Steven, thanks for you answer. But considering I have a MVC Controller and a query object implementing IQuery that uses the injected context to get database data, should I end the method lifeline without showing any call to the injected context members?

Comment: For the sequence diagram it's unimportant how those dependencies are injected, but you should show any interaction that is interesting for other developers to understand the system. If interaction with context members is interesting: show it.

Comment: I don't agree that it doesn't add value in all cases. Not all sequence diagrams are meant to describe the high level interactions with a system. In systems that have several stages of DI, it can be useful to nail certain steps down to a concrete class, because there may be behavior in the implementing class that you wish to express via the diagram. A good example is when there is only one implementing class, and the interface is only there for good abstraction practices and potential later development.

Comment: @michaelgulak what exactly do you mean by "systems that have several stages of DI"?

Comment: I mean systems that have many classes that are injected that interact with one another in complex ways. Oftentimes there is one implementing class for each interface and it is useful to know how those implementing classes ultimately behave together in one diagram.